# Detect same item selection for multiple select/dropdowns with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I am still new with learning all the awesome things Angular can do and one thing I am trying to look at is throwing an `ng-invalid` if a set of dropdowns have the same item selected.

For example, if I had three `select`s drop downs, each holding the items: apple, orange, peach. And the user selected apple for drop down 1 and 2, how can I use angular to detect this within the `select` tag, and throw an `ng-invalid`?

an example of the current `select` list I am using are as follows.

```
<span>
   <select ng-options="champ1.cID as champ1.cName for champ1 in Champions1 | orderBy: 'cName'" ng-init="0" ng-model="champ1">{{champ1.cName}}</select>
</span>
<span>
   <select ng-options="champ2.cID as champ2.cName for champ2 in Champions2 | orderBy: 'cName'" ng-init="0" ng-model="champ2">{{champ2.cName}}</select>
</span>
<span>
   <select ng-options="champ3.cID as champ3.cName for champ3 in Champions3 | orderBy: 'cName'" ng-init="0" ng-model="champ3">{{champ3.cName}}</select>
</span>
```

Would I use something like `ng-if`, or toss in some kind of `ng-class`? I am confused on where/how I would validate in regards to angular without doing some kind of directive or JQuery check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ui-validate for custom validations

```
<select ng-options="champ3.cID as champ3.cName for champ3 in Champions3 | orderBy: 'cName'" 
   ng-init="0" ng-model="champ3" 
   ui-validate="{'same' : 'champ1 == champ3 || champ2 == cmap3'}">
  {{champ3.cName}}
</select>
```

but above answer only an example. with ui-validate many more custom validations. please read about [ui-validate here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/).

you should read more about forms validations. sample links [here](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation)/[here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html) .